# Using ADODB (PHP database library) on OSX

Tags: php, macos, apache, firebird

According to the ADODB:

http://adodb.sourceforge.net/

documentation, it can be used for a number of databases on "Unix and Windows", so I'm assuming that includes OSX.

I've enabled PHP in my Apache installation, installed ADODB and modified include_path to include the ADODB directory, however I'm at a loss as to how to enable particular drivers. I have Firebird installed, so I'd prefer to connect to that, however I'm open to using some other database server.

I've managed to work it all out on a Windows install, however there seems to be scant information on how to do it on OSX.

Comment: I managed to work out how to use MySQL, but I'd still like to know if it's possible to use Firebird, and how.